# Angular file upload to micronaut rest api 403 error

Tags: javascript, java, angular, file-upload, micronaut

I am trying to upload multiple files to the micronaut Rest API. With postman and swagger, the files uploading is working fine in Micronaut Rest API, however, with the Angular app the post method is throwing 403 http error.

Micronaut controller method

```
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
@Post(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> images) {
            return this.iGoogleCloudService.uploadObject(images).flatMap(item -> {
               if (item.size() > 0)
                   return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.created(item));
               else
                   return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError(ConstantValues.TAG_FALLBACK));
            });
    }
```

Angular application

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop-zone w-75" file-drop (files)="onSelectFile($event)"
    [ngClass]="{'disableDiv': dragDropDisable}">
    <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="43" viewBox="0 0 50 43">
      <path
        d="M48.4 26.5c-.9 0-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v11.6h-43.3v-11.6c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v13.2c0 .9.7 1.7 1.7 1.7h46.7c.9 0 1.7-.7 1.7-1.7v-13.2c0-1-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7zm-24.5 6.1c.3.3.8.5 1.2.5.4 0 .9-.2 1.2-.5l10-11.6c.7-.7.7-1.7 0-2.4s-1.7-.7-2.4 0l-7.1 8.3v-25.3c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v25.3l-7.1-8.3c-.7-.7-1.7-.7-2.4 0s-.7 1.7 0 2.4l10 11.6z" />
    </svg>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onSelectFile($event.target.files)">
      <label for="file"><strong>Choose a file</strong><span class="dragndrop"> or drag it here</span>.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Component**

```
onSelectFile(files: FileList) {
    uploadFiles = [];
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      this.uploadFiles.push(files[i]);
    }
  }

onsubmit(){
    this.photoService.uploadImage(this.uploadFiles).subscribe()
}
```

Service

```
uploadImage(photos: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' });
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let index = 0; index < photos.images.length; index++) {
      formData.append('images', photos.images[index], photos.images[index].name);
    }
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/image`, formData, { headers: headers });
  }
```

Request form the browser

```
POST /api/v1/image HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 114826
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkExNDRGRkFGN0I5Q0NFQjk4MzY4QTBEMjI0MkMwOEI4IiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.MscnzuksdVyThuYMwGUMGUtr32I1Y_ko9TW0LeKr3qgB-YUYJ_GXiJ2KtZCx_BLrR_xzoEAzFVzGmLlwbr7-QLFz6hZ48UuBdwwnYmQFWoIJRderyD9tj_uPZn0FBdiAc7mboYHZaswb19w7ZRBcM9DadTOP91Iy0S_aT9cDVKRpGe5bhcwdFirMzt-Wn3wYWKwTw6ZrAya9O-i6K1ue2ID1SlsFYVKniZwpKmv4PRzlbK6SHqwJOLgA5qOsxJqo_amKRHgqOV9OTvIfole46zJTa3xkz9lhojqoE5xDVLM6bD5m7wH43N0yp76jxC7IPL3MMjhIb_7rLuKpjoFw-A
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Sec-GPC: 1
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

**Request payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAFf7zQ0AfQKOxvQ5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="Untitled-1.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryAFf7zQ0AfQKOxvQ5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="logopinktransparent.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryAFf7zQ0AfQKOxvQ5--
```

Postman request that works

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/image' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkExNDRGRkFGN0I5Q0NFQjk4MzY4QTBEMjI0MkMwOEI4IiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.Ol9Mt93yqOS15UUG2vIGZ58o5iEI7-r4G775BhH7BVudBJvI8haio22mNu_OkLOg5jTPiW_muZdcdpeSbdFIWEB1JhlH51y97AJVPpJs0yVAPOGCF7qIVVQP8JvrOGOl-vQziib1RJSzmVCmFUz96lcCfqjg5-NQlrqKZbacWTd30e7f6Q3Ruh0E9mL3wHm7ZosrST9s0qLG_av48apoOB_7FjNuz_ZGNmr4Tpxxaa2L_R1zbc6U5zRP5jYQ4J-kGPDJnHrFpa-JVrqon2k3zmJhfsxXO43BjokBYvfpnN3u5odHaY73eyLTJi_TvykM0N5RegUZ-gLaIiF5-AbKtQ' \
--form 'images=@"/Users/macbook/Desktop/Untitled-1.png"'
```

Comment: I don't see any authentication information anywhere in your request or client code.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- update the question with authentication

Answer (score 0):

**i notice this header 'enctype'  in your angular code.**
but enctype is not a http standard header,u should use Content-Type: multipart/form-data; to you header

Comment: Well after adding that header I am facing same issue